# jquery sortable getting changed dom items and sending ajax call

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable list of div's across multiple columns this [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/2bitcoder/h5rt2qgw/13/) has the demo. I can do the ajax call just fine,  I've added the update event to catch changes.

```
   update: function(event, ui) {
           // $.post('/reorder', $(selector).sortable('serialize'))
            //    .done(function() {
            //        alert('Updated')
          //    });
          //console.log($("#ready").sortable("serialize", { key: "sort" }));
        }
```

I just have no idea how I then get the id from each div container that has changed DOM position for a particular column. I've written the id number I need for the database update to the todo-task id property. The ajax call would need to be for each id number.

```
 <div class="task-list task-container ui-droppable ui-sortable ui-state-highlight" id="ready">
    <h3 class="ui-sortable-handle">Ready</h3>        
<div style="position: relative;" id="5329" class="todo-task ui-draggable-handle ui-sortable-handle"><div class="task-header"><div class="task-no">5329</div><div class="task-type">WBS</div></div><div class="task-body"><div class="task-title">New task</div></div><div class="task-footer"><div class="task-date">Due: 20/03/2015</div></div></div><div style="width: 277px; right: auto; height: 85px; bottom: auto; opacity: 1;" id="5327" class="todo-task ui-draggable-handle ui-sortable-handle"><div class="task-header"><div class="task-no">5327</div><div class="task-type">WBS</div></div><div class="task-body"><div class="task-title">Hand over to operations</div></div><div class="task-footer"><div class="task-date">Due: 01/10/2015</div></div></div><div style="position: relative;" id="839" class="todo-task ui-draggable-handle ui-sortable-handle"><div class="task-header"><div class="task-no">839</div><div class="task-type">Issue</div></div><div class="task-body"><div class="task-title">Demo Issue</div></div><div class="task-footer"><div class="task-date">Due: 28/01/2014</div></div></div><div style="position: relative;" id="841" class="todo-task ui-draggable-handle ui-sortable-handle"><div class="task-header"><div class="task-no">841</div><div class="task-type">Issue</div></div><div class="task-body"><div class="task-title">New Issue 1</div></div><div class="task-footer"><div class="task-date">Due: 22/08/2014</div></div></div></div>
```

I've seen other try and use serialize, but that doesn't seem to give me any result.

Any help appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

You can access ui.item in the [`.update()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) like this

`ui.item.attr('id')`

Update even looks like this

> update ( event, ui )

Sortable's update event has event and ui. You can make use of ui which has access to the current element being sorted. Since you already have the id stored in the dom element you can access it in the above mentioned way.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/h5rt2qgw/15/)

Hope this helps

Comment: Getting access to the div being dropped is okay, how do i get the id of all elements that have changed position?

Comment: for that you will have to maintain the structure of all the divs from the start in a variable. Once an element is moved you have to update that variable and then do the ajax

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I've used in the update event, this returns all items in a given drop area, then adds the id to an array, then removes any blank array elements, then sends the list in an ajax call for backend processing.

```
      update: function(event, ui) {
          var dropElement = $(this).closest('.ui-droppable').attr('id');

          var arr;
          $("#"+dropElement).each(function () {
              arr = $(this).sortable("toArray");
          });
          arr = $.grep(arr, function (n) {
              return (n);
          });
          console.log(arr);

          $.ajax({
              type: "POST", url: "/Processing/Projects/Methods/postSprintOrder/", data: { profileid: profileid, order: arr.toString() , actiontype: 'update' }, dataType: "html",
              success: function (response) {
              },
              error: function (response) {
                  alert(response);

              }
          });

      }
```